# Unable to start Redis in Windows Services. Error 1067: The process terminated unexpectedly

Tags: windows, redis, windows-services

I had installed redis-3.0.504. Followed the installation instructions and now redis-server is running in the port[image]

I had also installed redis in Windows services, but that is not running. I'm also not able to manually start the service. Getting the below error.

[image]

Any ideas to start the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right-click in the service in Window Services and go to Properties.

Then go to Log On tab and select Local System account.

Click on the Ok button and start the service.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you installed this via chocolatey, you need to add the following folder to allow the supplied redis.windows-service.conf to work:

```
C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\redis-64\Logs
```

If you didn't install via chocolatey, a missing log folder is still likely to be the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

The Redis port for Windows you are using has been deprecated.
As the last commit in that project suggests you can check out Memurai.
Memurai is a production grade software, actively maintained and freely available for development.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed with this: In `redis.windows.conf` file, the format is wrong:

```
Wrong: bind 127.0.0.1, 192.168.100.200

Right: bind 127.0.0.1 192.168.100.200
```